# How to insert an image in a template using HelperForm?

Tags: php, forms, prestashop-1.7

I am creating a custom module using PrestaShop 1.7 and I want to be be able to upload an image for the background. The image should be displayed if the field `background_image` is defined.

I am able to do it, but the image is outside of the form, as you can see in the image below.

[image: image in wrong position]

The image should be displayed immediately above the background image field, like this (see below).

[image: image in correct position]

Here is my .tpl file:

```
{if isset($background_image)}
<div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
    <div>
        <img src="/modules/cb_sectionaboutus/img/{$background_image}" class="img-thumbnail" width="400" />
    </div>
</div>
{/if}
```

And here is part of the main PHP file of the module:

```
/**
 * Load the configuration form
 */
public function getContent()
{
    /**
     * If values have been submitted in the form, process.
     */
    if (((bool)Tools::isSubmit('submitCb_sectionaboutusModule')) == true) {
        $this->postProcess();
    }

    $this->context->smarty->assign('module_dir', $this->_path);

    /* Passes the background image to the template */
    $data = $this->getDataFromDB();
    $background_image = $data['background_image'];
    $this->context->smarty->assign('background_image', $background_image);

    // About section & Documentation
    $output = $this->context->smarty->fetch($this->local_path.'views/templates/admin/configure.tpl');
    return $output.$this->renderForm();
}

/**
 * Create the form that will be displayed in the configuration of your module.
 */
protected function renderForm()
{
    $helper = new HelperForm();

    $helper->show_toolbar = false;
    $helper->table = $this->table;
    $helper->module = $this;
    $helper->default_form_language = $this->context->language->id;
    $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG', 0);

    $helper->identifier = $this->identifier;
    $helper->submit_action = 'submitCb_sectionaboutusModule';
    $helper->currentIndex = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', false)
        .'&configure='.$this->name.'&tab_module='.$this->tab.'&module_name='.$this->name;
    $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');

    $helper->tpl_vars = array(
        'fields_value' => $this->getConfigFormValues(), /* Add values for your inputs */
        'languages' => $this->context->controller->getLanguages(),
        'id_language' => $this->context->language->id
    );

    return $helper->generateForm(array($this->getConfigForm()));
}

/**
 * Create the structure of your form.
 */
protected function getConfigForm()
{
    return array(
        'form' => array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
                'icon' => 'icon-cogs'
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'label' => $this->l('Title'),
                    'name' => 'title',
                    'desc' => $this->l('Enter the title'),
                    'class' => 'rte',
                    'autoload_rte' => true
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'file',
                    'label' => $this->l('Background Image'),
                    'name' => 'background_image',
                    'desc' => $this->l('Maximum image size: ') . $this->upload_file_size_limit_in_mb . ' MB.',
                    'display_image' => true
                )
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
            ),
        ),
    );
}

/**
 * Set values for the inputs.
 */
protected function getConfigFormValues()
{
    $data = $this->getDataFromDB();

    return array(
        'title' => $data['title'],
        'background_image' => $data['background_image']
    );
}

/**
 * Get the data from the database
 */
public function getDataFromDB()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . $this->name . ' WHERE id_' . $this->name . ' = ' . 1;
    return Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql)[0];
}

/**
 * Save form data.
 */
protected function postProcess()
{
    /* Current data */
    $data_from_db = $this->getDataFromDB();

    /* New data */
    $form_values = $this->getConfigFormValues();

    /* Sets the background image as the old value, in case there is no new upload */
    $form_values['background_image'] = $data_from_db['background_image'];

    /* Validates the background image file */
    $file_name = $this->validateFile();
    /* Checks whether the background image has been successfully uploaded */
    if ($file_name) {
        /* Sets the new background image */
        $form_values['background_image'] = $file_name;
    }

    // Has rows in table --> UPDATE
    if ($data_from_db) {
        $sql = $sql = "UPDATE " . _DB_PREFIX_ . $this->name . " SET ";
        foreach (array_keys($form_values) as $key) {
            $sql .= $key . " = '" . $form_values[$key] . "', ";
        }
        $sql = trim($sql, " ");    // first trim last space
        $sql = trim($sql, ",");    // then trim trailing and prefixing commas
        $sql .= " WHERE id_" . $this->name . " = " . 1;
    }

    // No rows in table --> INSERT
    else {
        $columns = "id_cb_sectionaboutus, " . implode(", ", array_keys($form_values));
        $values = array_map('Tools::getValue', array_keys($form_values));
        $values = "1, " . "'" . implode("', '", array_values($values)) . "'";
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . $this->name . ' (' . $columns . ') VALUES (' . $values . ')';
    }

    Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);
}
```

How can I insert the uploaded image in the middle of the form using HelperForm?

I would prefer a solution with HelperForm, but I don't know if it works, so I will accept any answer tha gives me a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP file - `getConfigForm` function**

```
protected function getConfigForm()
{
    // ADDED THESE LINES
    $image = '';
    $background_image = $this->getDataFromDB()['background_image'];
    if ($background_image) {
        $image_url = $background_image ? '/modules/cb_sectionaboutus/img/' . $background_image : '';
        $image = '<div class="col-lg-6"><img src="' . $image_url . '" class="img-thumbnail" width="400"></div>';
    }

    return array(
        'form' => array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
                'icon' => 'icon-cogs'
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'file',
                    'label' => $this->l('Background Image'),
                    'name' => 'background_image',
                    'desc' => $this->l('Maximum image size: ') . $this->upload_file_size_limit_in_mb . ' MB.',
                    'display_image' => true,
                    'image' => $image  // ADDED THIS OPTION
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'label' => $this->l('Title'),
                    'name' => 'title',
                    'desc' => $this->l('Enter the title'),
                    'class' => 'rte',
                    'autoload_rte' => true
                )
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

**and remove everything from the template.**